# Is it possible to get Apple ID in my app?

Tags: iphone, ios5, app-store

I just wanted to know how to get the logged in apple id in the AppStore on an iPad/ iPhone?

I want to display that to the user.

Is that possible?

How to do that if that is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible, it would be a violation to the privacy

Comment: But, I just need only Apple ID not the password. I want to use it to send a mail which contains the Apple ID with in the subject of that mail.

Comment: yes, i understand, even that is not possible, apple dont want people to know the apple id of the user, some application could use these emails to bug the users with newsletters and mail shots